# How to select value from dropdown in javascript and multiply with entered number from textbox

Tags: javascript, html

I have a problem with my code. This is application who gives the select value from the drop-down list and multiply with the entered number in the text box and return the result. But the number is different for every case. Why when I select second option(in this case value="2") or other 3,4,5,6 they no work. Only first value="1" is working. Maybe I have a problem with if-else statement or no?

Where is my mistake? Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form>
Брой служители:
<select id="mySelect">
  <option value="1">1-10</option>
  <option value="2">11-30</option>
  <option value="3">31-80</option>
  <option value="4">81-150</option>
  <option value="5">151-300</option>
  <option value="6">300+</option>
</select>
</form>
<form name="razhod">
  Месечен разход: <input type="text" id="ourSum">
 </form>
<form>
    Вашата сума: <input type="text" id="result">
    <br><button type="button" onclick="sum()">Изчисли</button>

</form>

<script>

function sum() {
    if(document.getElementById('mySelect').value=="1")
    {
        var num1=0.90;
        var num2=document.getElementById('ourSum').value;
        var res=document.getElementById('result');
        var myResult=num1*num2;
        document.getElementById('result').value=myResult;


    }
    else if(document.getElementById('mySelect').value=="2")
    {
        var num1=0.85;
        var num2=document.getElementById('ourSum').value;
        var res=document.getElementById('result');
        var myResult=num1*num2;
        document.getElementById('result').value=myResult;


    }
    else if(document.getElementById('mySelect').value=="3")
    {
        var num1=0.70;
        var num2=document.getElementById('ourSum').value;
        var res=document.getElementById('result');
        var myResult=num1*num2;
        document.getElementById('result').value=myResult;


    }
    else if(document.getElementById('mySelect').value=="4")
    {
        var num1=0.65;
        var num2=document.getElementById('ourSum').value;
        var res=document.getElementById('result');
        var myResult=num1*num2;
        document.getElementById('result').value=myResult;


    }
    else if(document.getElementById('mySelect').value=="5")
    {
        var num1=0.60;
        var num2=document.getElementById('ourSum').value;
        var res=document.getElementById('result');
        var myResult=num1*num2;
        document.getElementById('result').value=myResult;


    }
    else if(document.getElementById('mySelect').value=="6")
    {
        var num1=0.55;
        var num2=document.getElementById('ourSum').value;
        var res=document.getElementById('result');
        var myResult=num1*num2;
        document.getElementById('result').value=myResult;


    }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Side note:  Since the only difference in the code you currently have broken out in if/then statements is `num1`, why not use one block of code with and conditionally assign the value of `num1`?  That would reduce a lot of repetition.

Comment: Can you give me example for this ? I thinked about optimization for my code but i didn't succeed.

Comment: Other than ridiculously long and unoptimized ... it is working fine. Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/827qmaek/

Comment: Thanks to all ! I solved my problem !

Answer (score 1):

I've tested your code, and its working correctly as far as I can see. Although as noted by the comments, the code is very long and repetitive.

The problem you're seeing is likely your browser, or system setup that is causing this issue. I will note the `<form>` tags you're using don't look right. It could be that they are trying to submit a value, which is re-setting your page (as though you refreshed it). Try removing them and test again.

Finally, here's an example of how you could make the code more readable:

```
function sum() {

    var mySelect = document.getElementById('mySelect');
    var ourSum = document.getElementById('ourSum');
    var res = document.getElementById('result');

    if (mySelect.value == "1")
    {
        res.value = ourSum.value * 0.9;
    }
    else if(mySelect.value=="2")
    {
        res.value = ourSum.value * 0.85;
    }
    else if(mySelect.value=="3")
    {
        res.value = ourSum.value * 0.7;
    }

    // and so on...
}
```

Comment: Thank you ! But what i have to use instead <form> ?

Comment: A `<form>` is used to submit data to a server. Generally you would have a single form wrapping all of your fields, and a submit button. However, given the way you have written the code, I'm assuming that you've obtained the result, and you're not looking to send it to a server? In this case a `<div>` would be better than `<form>`. The `<div>` is a container, used to divide html into sections. This would be more appropriate for layout.

Comment: Thank you ! I have changed this(form to div).

Answer (score 0):

The code is working but it is ridiculously long and unoptimized. Here is the same code in very few lines:

```
function sum() {        
    var opts = [0, .9, .85, .7, .65, .6, .55];    
    var num1 = opts[document.getElementById('mySelect').value];    
    var num2 = document.getElementById('ourSum').value;
    var res = document.getElementById('result');    
    res.value=num1*num2;
}
```

[and the working jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/827qmaek/1/)